# innerHTML not being updated after changing value of input (checked = true/false/"checked")

Tags: javascript

Brief:  I need to grab the information in parentElement, but I need the input information updated.  when I am grabbing the innerHTML of parentElement, after the box is unchecked, it still shows up checked. The html is not reflecting changes I've made with javascript.

I have a small snippet of my code here:  http://jsfiddle.net/7993K/8/

```
<div id="parentElement">
<label id="thisLabel">
    <input type="checkbox" id="idnumber" checked="checked"> Bring Mail Inside
</label>
</div>
<p>
<a onClick="checkit()">Check it out</a>
</p>
<p onclick="checkToggle()">change to false</p>


function checkit() {
alert(document.getElementById("parentElement").innerHTML);
}
function checkToggle() {
element = document.getElementById("thisLabel");
element.childNodes[0].checked = false;
alert("the checkbox is checked: " + element.childNodes[0].checked);
}
```

*The slightly longer version of why I am going about it like this:*
This is a large form that a site inspector checked out.  It is brought into an online software app, and the lady in charge of communication with clients will review this information, speak back with the inspector on the phone.  This form is saved in a database as html.  After the woman is done reviewing the form, there may be a box or two that wasn't checked, that she would like to check, before emailing to the client ( there were issues, needed to be fixed, now that they are fixed, she can send out the proper report that everything was checked off)

She checks the boxes off, but they don't update the HTML, they only change the value, which will show, but won't show up when I get the innerHTML of parentElement.  You will see in my JSFIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/7993K/8/:

Click check it out upon loading:  checked = checked

uncheck box: checked = checked

change to false:  alert confirms the checked property is false, but check it out shows the innerHTML as checked.

I will need to access this innerHTML with the proper information loaded (as in, if it is checkmarked, the html should reflect that)

PRE-EDIT:  I think I can do this by making an event onclick of the label.  That event takes the ("parentElement").innerHTML and split it in a few different places and put it back together with the right checked value.  Will be slightly different if the input isn't checked to begin with.  That is the only way I can think of doing this, and it just doesn't seem like the right way.

Comment: Side note: your `element` variable is an implicit global, don't forget your `var`.

Comment: thank you.  I did this quickly and should practice better to keep in good form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because `element.childNodes[0].checked = false;` is setting the *DOM property*, which is a separate entity than the *HTML attributes*.

Your `checkit` function should also be interrogating the *DOM property*, not checking the `innerHTML`.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003819/properties-and-attributes-in-html) for more information about DOM properties and HTML attributes.

Comment: set/removeAttribute is what I really would like to be editing.  I started by learning jQuery... and have recently decided to learn the actual javascript language.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I picked this answer because I needed to edit the HTML to send the HTML in an email to the client.  I checked if the inputs were 
    .checked == true  // then .setAttribute("checked", "checked")

    .checked == false  // then .removeAttribute("checked")

Comment: In reality, it helped me much more than just this simple piece I was working on.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

The state of checkboxes and the value of input boxes are NOT a part of the source HTML.

For proof of this, try putting a textbox on a page with `value="old"`, change the value, then compare `element.getAttribute("value")` and `element.value` - they're not the same.

You really should save the state of the form, rather than the HTML behind it.

Comment: I'm looking to retain the HTML so that I can send out this innerHTML as an Email and send it to the printer as part of a report.

Comment: setAttribute / removeAttribute seems to work?

Would I really want to be using the state of the form?