# Reflect DOM property change of input checkbox into innerHTML attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, checkbox, innerhtml

I have a webform with contenteditable elements and checkboxes, which on submission returns the innerHTML of the surrounding div (nothing I can change about this).
For obvious reasons, this means that changes of the contenteditable elements are submitted, whereas changes of the checkbox-states are not, because as DOM properties, they are not part of the HTML attributes.

I've found a relatively simple workaround, which is to append a click-event to the elements surrounding the checkboxes and modifying the innerHTML.

Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/9Lkoaq3y/

```
$( ".checkboxes" ).click(function() {
  if (this.firstChild.checked) this.innerHTML=this.innerHTML.split("input").join("input checked=\"checked\"");
  else this.innerHTML=this.innerHTML.split("checked=\"checked\" ").join("");
});
```

I was wondering, however, whether there was a more failsafe, elegant and general way to approach this, which would also work on other form elements.
In short, I don't like my ugly hack.

A related question has been asked here: [innerHTML not being updated after changing value of input (checked = true/false/"checked")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14736238/innerhtml-not-being-updated-after-changing-value-of-input-checked-true-false) but without an elegant solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution I could find (just to end this unanswered question), was to write the checked property into the checked-attribute of all checkboxes and radiobuttons everytime one of them changes a value.

This brief jquery-code takes care of this, and makes sure only those input-elements have their attribute changed where the property and the attribute do not yet correspond.

```
$("input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio]").change(function () {
     $("input[checked='checked']:not(:checked)").each(function (index) {
         $(this).removeAttr('checked');
     });
     $("input:not([checked='checked']):checked").each(function (index) {
         $(this).attr('checked', 'true');
     });
});
```